# What does this line mean in the android programming?

Tags: java, android

This is the line I got confused with.

```
InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD
```

in this program:

```
public class TextPlay extends Activity {

    Button clickMe;
    TextView txtply;
    ToggleButton toggle;
    EditText et1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_text_play);
        clickMe= (Button)findViewById(R.id.txt_ply_Clickme);
        txtply= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_ply_textview);
        toggle= (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.txt_ply_toggle);
        et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_ply_edittext);
        toggle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(toggle.isChecked()) {
                    et1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                }
                else {
                    et1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.text_play, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: what don't you understand `setInputType` documentation or `|` <= "binary or operator"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are flags. If you read the documentation here it explains it them further: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html

The | operator allows you to combine the two. What do these actually affect? By reading the summary of the linked page, it explains it:

Bit definitions for an integer defining the basic content type of text held in an Editable object. Supported classes may be combined with variations and flags to indicate desired behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

This is the type of data that is expected in this field:

InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT: Means that you expect users to write a text.
InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD: Means that you expect users to write a numeric password.

This can be done also inside EditText in xml layout file using input type:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/phone"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="@string/phone_hint"
android:inputType="phone" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TYPE_CLASS_TEXT Class for normal text

TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD  Variation of TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER: entering a numeric password.
```

From Android doc:
Bit definitions for an integer defining the basic content type of text held in an Editable object. Supported classes may be combined with variations and flags to indicate desired behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

InputType declares the type of your input as its name.

`TYPE_CLASS_TEXT`  this is for regular text, if you use number instead of text, it accepts number only and so. Btw welcome to StackOverflow, next time you post a question, don't use a title like "What does this  line mean". I suggest you to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).